# List of lambda functions, elements are somehow being linked?

Tags: python, list, lambda, reference

Consider the following piece of code, which creates a list of several functions:

```
func = lambda a,x: a*x

func_list = []
for i in range(3):
    __tmp = lambda x: (i+1)*x
    func_list.append(__tmp)

x = 2
print func_list[0](x)
print func_list[1](x)
print func_list[2](x)
```

The expected output is `2,4,6`, however the actual output is `6,6,6`. Somehow, the first and second elements of the list were changed to the value of the third element! I am not sure why this is happening? I've seen issues where people do something like `list = [0]*4` in which all elements would refer to the same entity, but my case seems to be different.

Comment: Hint: what value is `i` at the point where you are calling the functions?

Comment: I see, but how do I fix this?